# Intent and activity relation retention when the activity is killed by OS

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

What is the relation between an Activity and the Intent that is started it, in the following case.

When OS destroy that Activity and user move back to it again at some point , seems like again OS use info from its lastly started Intent , Does OS store the Intent fro each Activity in a task?

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation An intent is an abstract description of an operation to be performed.

you can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

and also from the documentation An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do.

you can read about it [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: yes I got this point. But I am talking about when an Activity is killed by OS and then user return back to it in a later time. How OS know about its related Intent ?

Comment: in what way, close the app, and then restart it? or go from one activity back to a previous one? in what way?

Comment: go from one activity back to a previous one?

Comment: startActivityForResult(intent) will return the method OnActivityResult() to the activty, startActivity(intent) wont, either way the activity process will follow the Activity LifeCycle

Answer (score 0):

In short, **Activity** is an application component for displaying an user interface.
On the other hand, An **intent** is a system message which can be broadcasted around the system to notify other applications of an event, or it can be used to request that the system display a new activity.

When you move from one user interface to another you need to launch that new user interface with an intent.That's the relation between them you can say.

When Android kills an application and an user navigates back to the app, `onCreate()` is fired with a **new Activity**. It turns out the **intent extras** are available when an activity is re-created after an application got killed.